# Need help. I'm going to install Android 4.1 on at&t HTC One X

Tags: updates, htc, att

I've just started upgrading of my HTC One X at&t version.
[Jelly Bean (Android 4.1) released for AT&T HTC One X .... but how to install it on unlocked AT&T phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41176/jelly-bean-android-4-1-released-for-att-htc-one-x-but-how-to-install-it)
I followed this link.
There are instructions how to update it in the answer in this link.
When i entered into recovery mode, TWRP manager menu appears.
on the step 4:
-"Now, press and hold both the Volume Up and down key and then while holding them, press and release the power button. After releasing the Volume rocker key, you will get a Blue Menu along with a set of options which will indicate that the device has been successfully landed in the Recovery Mode."
but this combination of buttons just lock screen, and there is only Swipe To Unlock button.
Can anyone help me? what should i do in this case?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The description points to booting into the recovery mode, so you must do that while the device is *switched off* (not while it's running).